# "From an attic of a building" vs. "from the attic of a building"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, articles

Could you choose the most natural sentence, please?

> 1. As a kitten, she fell from **an** attic of a nine-storey bulding into a ventilation shaft.
> 2. As a kitten, she fell from **the** attic of a nine-storey bulding into a ventilation shaft.

Comment: From *the attic,* certainly. If you say *an attic,* it sounds like the nine-story building has more than one attic.

Comment: One question per question, please. And a more descriptive title would be nice. And proper tags and formatting. You've been a member for three months, you know how it works. Thanks.

Comment: I thought  maybe it should have been  'an  attic' because it's first mention. What do you think about it?

Comment: ... and still zero percent.

Comment: How is it in your language? I've no idea where you come from, but all languages that I know (at least a little) I can say that they handle it the same way.

Comment: Note that "storey" is a British spelling. In proper English like we use in America, it's written "story".

Answer (score 1):

**Attic:** space within the roof of a house

> My house has two small rooms in the **attic**.

So, clearly only one **attic** is possible in a house. Same is with a building (with apartments), as there is only *one* roof. Thus, the more natural sounding (and *correct*) alternative is:

> 2.As a kitten, she fell from **the** attic of a nine-storey bulding into a ventilation shaft.

Comment: I once lived in a house with two attics (they had separate entrances, and weren't connected). We still called the main one "the attic".

Comment: @PeterShor I have made an edit to my answer. I hope that clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have more than one attic in a building if a wall extends through the roof-space to the roof — it's often called a firewall and its purpose is to stop fire spreading through the entire roof-space.

**So *an attic* is entirely correct,** if slightly unusual because most buildings aren't large enough to require firewalls to create separate attics. Perhaps a nine-storey building would be large enough.

As for the "most natural" sentence, it probably **is** *the attic*, simply because most buildings have only one.

Comment: I beg to differ with you. As the meaning of the word **attic** says, its the space within the roof of a house, so it doesn't matter how many partitions you make in the attic. It will still remain _one_ attic.

Comment: @rudra: The [meaning of attic](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=attic&title=21st&sourceid=Mozilla-search): A space or room at the top of a house under the roof (not necessarily *the* space). Trust someone who has had to deal with attics and firewalls.

Comment: @rudra I live in a counterexample. My house has two attics which are not separated by a partition. Have you never seen a house where the roof has multiple gables?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I still disagree with you. The meaning I have written is from an Oxford dictionary. So, i don't think it would be wrong at all.

Comment: @MarkBeadles That's an interesting point you make. But then you have to consider whether you can say that your house has more than one roof (which i think is not correct).

Comment: @rudra My house has one roof. It has multiple attics. Your source may be "an" Oxford dictionary, but "the" Oxford English dictionary, 2ed, 1989 says: "Attic 2, sense 3: The highest storey of a house, or a room in it; a garret." The 'room' or 'garret' sense clearly allows for multiple attics.

Comment: Hmm, I'm tempted to say that if you had two unconnected spaces, you could call it "two attics". But if you had a building with two unconnected areas about the second floor, would you say that you have "two third floors"?

Comment: So if I know for sure that there are two or more  attics I  use 'an attic' when I mention one of them for the first time. And if there is only one attic and I mention it for 'the first time' I still use 'the attic' and not 'an attic,' am I right?

Comment: @Monica: I reckon so, yes, and it appears most others do.

Comment: But what is the rule of using 'the' instead of 'an' or 'a' before a noun that you mention for the first time? Like in my sentence in which there was only one attic and it  was mentioned for the first time, but the correct option was still 'the' and not 'an'.

Comment: Another example; I like a/the church in our neighborhood. 'The'  seems to be more correct to me.